# Tool For Viewing Exchange of SOAP Messages between my browser and portal server

Tags: web-services, soap, portal

I am investigating an issue regarding particular portal.

Is there a tool that I can used to be able to view the exchange of SOAP Messages between my browser and the portal.

I basically have been looking at my Firebug but I cant seem to find the SOAP message exchange?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called Fiddler. It's basically an HTTP traffic sniffer. You can view every HTTP connect from your browser, and responses, amongst other things.

Comment: I tried this tool but I only see HTTP traffic for text/html/images but I am unable to view SOAP responses.  I am not sure if theres any configuration that i have missed.  Thanks